# Devo realmente usar getters e setters para todas variáveis públicas nas classes?

Tags: c++, getters-setters

Então este assunto parece bem polêmico mas ao mesmo tempo não vejo um concesso entre os desenvolvedores.

1. Há quem diga que getters e setters são regra 100% para acessar qualquer variável dentro de uma classe. Ou seja, se eu tiver 10 variáveis, terei 10 getters e 10 setters;
2. Há que diga que getters e setters deveriam ser usados só para situações específicas;
3. Finalmente há quem defenda que não se deve usar absolutamente getters e setters para variáveis públicas, uma vez que elas são públicas e facilmente acessíveis.

Então, numa estrutura simples como essa:

```
class exemplo
{
public:
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    string g, h, i, j;
    double k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t;
};
```

... onde há 20 variáveis públicas, tenho realmente que ter 20 getters e 20 setters?

Comment: Qual seria o benefício em escrever getters e setters para esses 20 membros de dado?

Comment: Os atributos são públicos, mesmo implementando ou não os getters/setters, você nunca vai garantir que todos os clientes da classe vão usá-los.

Comment: O uso de getters e setters é recomendado em todos os cenários, independentemente do número de variáveis-membro.  Regra geral, os únicos casos onde getters e setters são dispensáveis são quando as variáveis são qualificadas de privadas, ou quando se trata de uma classe-valor.